# Type casting function loaded from a library to function with empty interface parameter

Tags: go

I'm developing a simple plugin system for a web application so that the handler could be loaded and set to a particular path at application startup time. When I use handler with known type, both by the main web app and the module library, everything work as expected. For example when using func(echo.Context) error as the handler signature (I'm using echo labstack framework).

But when I use function signature with empty interface to cater more dynamic client needs such as func(interface{}) (interface{}, int, error), the type conversion is not working.

Can we type cast a specific type (which is loaded from a library) to a more generic type? Or maybe there are other ways to accomplish this?

```
p, err := plugin.Open(libname)    
sym, err := p.Lookup(handlerName)
handler, ok := sym.(func(interface{}) (interface{}, int, error))
```

Error Message -> invalid type assertion: sym.() (non-interface type 
    func(main.HelloConfig) (interface{}, int, error) on left)

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you just minimize your question with a simple example, so we could understand better. Thank you.

Comment: The error is generated in line handler, ok := sym.(func(interface{}) (interface{}, int, error))

Comment: *"Can we type cast a specific type (which is loaded from a library) to a more generic type?*" No, we can't.

Comment: which is happen when I try to type cast function I got from library by means of golang plugin library, to a function definition which has empty interface as a parameter and return type.

Comment: Also note that `v.(T)` is a type assertion, not a type cast. There's no type casting in Go.